# how to rename the image from image picker in flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, rename, gallery, imagepicker

I am picking a image from gallery/taking a photo using   image_picker: ^0.6.7+4 package.

```
void takePhoto(ImageSource source) async {
final pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(
  source: source,
);
setState(() {
  _imageFile = pickedFile;
});
}
```

and I get image name as

image_picker_A0EBD0C1-EF3B-417F-9F8A-5DFBA889118C-18492-00001AD95CF914D3.jpg

Now I want to rename the image.

How can I rename it?

Comment: this link helps,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59896345/rename-a-file-image-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to save that image somewhere before you can rename it. Try this:

```dart
void takePhoto(ImageSource source) async{
  final image = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: source);
  final newImage = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/your_name.jpg');
}
```